# bind zone file SOA - ttl not being honored

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

This is my SOA for one of my zones. Shouldn't this give me a 10 minute TTL for all the records in this zone? dig is telling me differently. What do I have wrong here?

```
@       1D IN   SOA     ns.dtdo.net.     root.dtdo.net. (
                                    2012062101 ; Serial
                                    10M ; Refresh
                                    10M ; Retry
                                    7D ; Expire
                                    10M ) ; Minimum TTL

$ dig @8.8.8.8 colorado.dtdo.us
.
.
;; ANSWER SECTION:
colorado.dtdo.us.       85949   IN      A       208.139.198.178
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 600       ; 10 minutes
```

- this added on the top of the zone file will give you TTL 10min for all entries.
  The TTL in SOA is for domain name and not for the records.

If you have records which do e.g. 1 minute, on the bottom add:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 600       ; 10 minutes

.. all your zone fine which will default to 10 minutes
ftp IN A 1.1.1.1

$TTL 300       ; 5 minutes
www IN A 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still seeing some strange results when I dig @8.8.8.8, but that could be because stuff is already cached. I'll check everything again in the morning.

Comment: But this is not the best solution to put 10min TTL on all records. The smallest values for high usage is 1h for all records and absolute minimum is 1m for dynamic ones, like "www" if you have some sort of monitoring and load balancing on it. But the 10m should work just fine, however the NS records should have higher value.